# Creating json from lists using zip

Tags: python

I have 2 lists as follows:

```
>> a = [u'username', u'first name', u'last name']
>> b = [[u'user1', u'Jack', u'Dawson'], [u'user2', u'Roger', u'Federer']]
```

I am trying to get an output json like the following:

```
[
  {
    "username":"user1",
    "first name":"Jack",
    "last name":"Dawson"
  },
  {
    "username":"user2",
    "first name":"Roger",
    "last name":"Federer"
  }
]
```

I am trying to use the zip command as follows:

```
>> x = []
>> for i in range(0, len(b)):
..   x += zip(a,b[i])
..
```

But this wasn't givin my desired output. How do i implement this?

Comment: Although it looks like the question has be answered, this really isn't a proper question.  "this wasn't givin my desired output" means "I am unhappy".  Describe the actual output and what is wrong with it. (In this case, the problem is that `+=` means "concatenate the source array onto the destination array" and not, as you seem to think "*append* the source value onto the destination array".  That function is performed by, not surprisingly, `.append()`.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`zip` will just return a list of tuples. You forgot to convert this list of tuples to a dictionary. You can do it using the `dict` constructor. Also you can avoid for loop completely: `[dict(zip(a, row)) for row in b]` will create your desired list of dictionaries. Then after building the list you can convert to json. For example:

```
a = [u'username', u'first name', u'last name']
b = [[u'user1', u'Jack', u'Dawson'], [u'user2', u'Roger', u'Federer']]
import json
print(json.dumps([dict(zip(a, row)) for row in b], indent=1))
```

Output:

```
[
 {
  "username": "user1", 
  "first name": "Jack", 
  "last name": "Dawson"
 }, 
 {
  "username": "user2", 
  "first name": "Roger", 
  "last name": "Federer"
 }
]
```

Comment: This is good python code, but you should point out that the OP made two errors and you are correcting both.  One, the substantial error, was that he confused += (concatenation) with append.  The other, a stylistic mistake, was using an explicit loop instead of a comprehension.

Comment: Thanks, @Malvolio. Hope it's better now.